# Is this a "teachers' lounge"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

In Japan, high school teachers have a place like this, where they each have a desk:

[image]

Can this be called a teachers' lounge? Or there's a better alternative?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Japanese schools have a different cultural expections from schools in the UK (I've worked in both).

The staffroom(UK), or teacher's lounge(USA) is a room with soft furnishing, and usually a place to make tea and coffee.  There might be a couple of desks with computers, but the staffroom/teacher's lounge is not mainly a work area, it is a space in which to relax.

There may be offices, perhaps open plan offices at which teachers can prepare lessons. More senior staff have private offices, less senior staff have shared or "hot-desk" offices.  Some teachers use a classroom as an office.

In contrast in every school I've been in in Japan, there is a central open-plan room for teachers. It is not a lounge but a work room.

The "teachers' office" or "Staff work room"  might be a general description. But perhaps the fact that is a work space, not a relaxation space doesn't matter.  For example if you are writing from the point of view of a child.  This is just a room which only teachers can go into. In context, it may not matter whether it is a lounge or an office.  So you could just call it the "**Teachers' Room**".

Comment: For the most part in the US, teachers have an assigned classroom and do all their work there. In Japan, students have an assigned classroom and teachers come to that classroom for lessons. Teachers have to do their work in these communal teachers' rooms.

Comment: Yeah, I've never known a teacher to have a private office in the US. I know of one shared office that the science teachers share because it's also the prep room.

Answer (score 9):

It looks more like a faculty office to me, but the big difference would depend on whether it's used for work or relaxation.

Comment: Yeah.  I would expect a lounge to have comfortable seats and no desks.  Where you can *lounge*

Answer (score 4):

In British English it would be called a **Teachers' room**. Note the possessive apostrophe comes after the plural suffix "s"

In the UK, *the teachers’ room*  is also known as the *staff room*, or *[**staffroom**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/staffroom)*. I believe that the terms *teachers lounge* or the *[faculty lounge](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/faculty-lounge#:%7E:text=(%CB%88st%C9%91%CB%90fru%CB%90m%20),Copyright%20%C2%A9%20HarperCollins%20Publishers)* is more commonly used in the US.

A staffroom/teachers’room is a place where teachers can relax before or after class, have lunch, grab a cup of coffee, plan lessons, and arrange meetings with parents.

> ‘Even Mr West, the teacher who was supposed to be supervising, had popped out to the staffroom for a coffee.’

Comment: This doesn't look like a place where you can relax or have lunch, although fine for marking.

Comment: @StuartF  I agree the decor and atmosphere looks more sobre than we might expect in Europe and that's probably due to the Japanese culture. But in the UK a room where teachers can relax between classes and have a sarnie (not a plate of carbonara!)  is either a teachers' room or a staffroom.

Comment: We use the the apostrophe after the "s" as well because the room is for the faculty, not an individual teacher.

Comment: Back in the 70s when I was at a UK grammar school, from what I ever saw of it glimpsed through the door as teachers came & went, the staffroom was somewhere between a lounge & a communal office space, half & half. Tea & sofas, desks, typewriters & Gestetners [no computers or photocopiers in those days, of course].

Comment: When I began teaching in Australian secondary schools in the 1970s the older staff rooms contained teachers' desks for perhaps 20 teachers. Newer staff rooms had comfortable seats, tea and coffee, and food heating facilities. Over time teachers dispersed from the large staff rooms into smaller offices, and the expectation came to be that a staff room would not primarily be a work space. I believe that in primary schools, where teachers taught in only one classroom and could maintain a workspace in that room, staff rooms were always seen as spaces for time off, rather than for work.